# Send a NDEF message to a phone

Tags: arduino, nfs, ndef

Hi I'm trying to send a message to my phone using an Arduino Uno with a PN532, this is the code I'm using:

```cpp
PN532_SPI pn532spi(SPI, 10);
SNEP nfc(pn532spi);
uint8_t ndefBuf[128];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("NFC Peer to Peer Example - Send Message");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Send a message to Peer");

  NdefMessage message = NdefMessage();
  message.addTextRecord("");

  int messageSize = message.getEncodedSize();
  if (messageSize > sizeof(ndefBuf)) {
    Serial.println("ndefBuf is too small");
    while (1) {
    }
  }

  message.encode(ndefBuf);
  if (0 >= nfc.write(ndefBuf, messageSize)) {
    Serial.println("Failed");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Success");
  }

  delay(3000);
}
```

The problem is that it always enters the "failed" part and and it does not work.
Any solution?

Comment: I suggest looking at the implementation of ```SNEP```. It is possible that ```nfc.write(ndefBuf, messageSize)``` returns different values depending on types of error. ```-1``` for a particular error and ```-2``` for another type of error and so on.

Comment: @KentaroOkuda the error is -1, do you what it stands for?

Comment: what library are you using? if you are using this one (https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532/blob/master/PN532/snep.cpp), ```-1``` means that it failed to activate the target. dig into your library and see how ```write``` function is implemented.

Comment: @KentaroOkuda yes I'm using that one, sorry I'm a newbie and I have no idea on how can I fix this, can you help me?

Comment: ```llcp.activate(timeout)``` is failing. you need to find out why it is failing. I think you can enable debug by commenting in line 4 of ```PN532_debug.h```. (```#define DEBUG```). this way, the program prints out helpful info on your serial monitor.

Comment: @KentaroOkuda this is what I get: SAMConfig
write:  14 1 14 1
Time out when waiting for ACK
write:  8C 0 0 0 0 0 0 40 1 FE F BB BA A6 C9 89 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 FF FF 1 FE F BB BA A6 C9 89 0 0 6 46 66 6D 1 1 10 0
Time out when waiting for ACK
failed to activate PN532 as a target
SAMConfig
write:  14 1 14 1
Time out when waiting for ACK
write:  8C 0 0 0 0 0 0 40 1 FE F BB BA A6 C9 89 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 FF FF 1 FE F BB BA A6 C9 89 0 0 6 46 66 6D 1 1 10 0
Time out when waiting for ACK
failed to activate PN532 as a target

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197805/discussion-between-francesco-bordignon-and-kentaro-okuda).

Comment: The library is sending a TgInitAsTarget command (indicated by the 8C value) but is not getting the expected ACK message back from the PN532, hence the timeout.  It sounds like the PN532 may not be connected.  Can you share the code where nfc is instantiated and configured?  I don't know this library but I see there is a connect() method on the LLCP object which is involved in sending the TgInitAsTarget command.  Are you calling that anywhere?